# Error when trying to access the database in visual studio

Tags: c#

There is an error that pops up when i try to add a connection with access database into server explorer in visual studio, The error is 'Unrecognized database format.' Is there someway for me to fix this error?

Comment: Please provide some sample in your post (e.g. code).

Comment: which database are you using SQL Server or MS Access??

Comment: the database is MS access, as for the code i'm not sure if i can access it